# Whenever I use ajax to get data from my textarea and insert it into mysql, line breaks are not inserted

Tags: mysql

I am using ajax to insert a form using GET.  When that form is submitted, it goes into a mysql database.  I know that the error is occurring when this data is being submitted into mysql and not when I am retrieving it.  My problem is that all line breaks, and when you press the "enter" key are not being submitted into the database.  All of the text just goes in as a straight line without breaks or anything of the sort.  I would appreciate any help as to figuring out how to get these breaks to actually be inserted into mysql because this is a big problem for my site.  Any help is very much appreciated.

Here is the code for the ajax that I am using

```
$echovar400=
      "
    <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>

function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert('Your browser broke!');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('pagecomments');
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;

    }
}
var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
var wpm = document.getElementById('wpm').value;
var queryString = '?age=' + age + '&wpm=' + wpm;
ajaxRequest.open('GET', 'ajaxprofilechat.php' + queryString, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 

}

</script>

<form name='myForm' method='GET' >
<textarea rows='4' name='message' class='comment' maxlength='250' id='age' wrap='hard'>        </textarea><br><h40>
<input type='hidden' id='wpm' value='$profilename'/>
<input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction()' value='Comment' />
</form>
    ";
  }
  ?>
```

I realize that is not the start of the php, but the rest is unimportant.

```
here is the code for ajaxprofilechat

$age = strip_tags($_GET['age']);
$wpm = $_GET['wpm'];
// Escape User Input to help prevent SQL Injection
$wpm = mysql_real_escape_string($wpm);
$chatname6 = ($_SESSION['username']);
$message6 = $_GET['site_message'];
$month6 = date("F");
$dayofmonth6 = date("d");
$year6 = date("Y");
$date10 = "$month6 $dayofmonth6 $year6";

$hours6 = date("g");
$min6 = date("i");
$sec6 = date("s");
$amorpm6 = date("A");
$time6 = "$hours6:$min6 $amorpm6";

if (strlen($age)>4)
{
mysql_connect("","","") or die($error);
mysql_select_db("") or die($error);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO guestbook VALUES             ('','$wpm','$chatname6','$age','$date10','$time6')");
 echo "&nbsp;<h80><b>Comment Posted</b></h80<p><p>";
 }
 else
 {
 echo "&nbsp;<h80><b>Your comment must be greater than four characters</b></h80><p>";
 }
 ?>
```

Any help would be great.  Thanks!

if you need to see my site to look at the error, here is a link to my profile page http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/profile.php?u=eggo

---

Guys I have literally tried everything that you have told me, and in every possible way.  However, i am still encountering the same problem.  Should I try to use the POST method of ajax instead of GET?  Do you have any other suggestions?  And thank you for the help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$message6 = nl2br($_GET['site_message']);`, then you don't have to worry about the `\n` or `\r\n` in your MySQL record since it will be stored as HTML `<br />` and will display as intended during output. If you need to put it back in a textfield for edit, you'd simply use `br2nl()`.

```
function br2nl($str)
{
    return preg_replace('#<br\s*?/?>#i', "\n", $str); 
}
```

Comment: yes, I know about nl2br.  But my problem is when the code inserts into the database.  The code is inserting as one long string, even if there is a break in the textarea.  I have just spent 4 hours trying every solution and the ones that you guys posted.  I am almost sure that the error is going into the database and not retrieving the data.  Please any other suggestions.  I am about to give up at this point...

Comment: What is a field type?  Sorry, but i'm still a novice at programming.  But I know for sure that the problem occurs when data is being inserted into the database.

Comment: oh lol, nvm the field type is text.  I had a bit of a brain fart, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap the POST data from the textarea with the nl2br() function

[nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)